# Nivo Slider not loading

Tags: wordpress, web, slider, syntax-error

I have just made some really minor changes to this site http://berlin-hipster.de/andersdenken/ and now there has been a lot broken I suppose it is just a missing semicolon or something like this but I could fix nearly everything except for the Nivo Slider who is now just showing the loading gif for an infinite amount of time. I really tried everything I know, could you take a look at the site at tell me maybe?

I am using the Optima theme for Wordpress and until now, everything worked like a charm...

Comment: did you check your console for errors ? its showing these js errors SyntaxError: syntax error
[Break On This Error]  

delay:       ,   // one second delay on mouseout

Comment: I did yes, but I don't know how to change it cause it seems like I can't reach this code area...I'll take a closer look!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would cause a problem, but you have # in your image titles.

```
<img src="http://berlin-hipster.de/andersdenken/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Hamsterrad-mit-Mann_erweitert_sw.jpg" alt="" title="# SliderCaption1"/>
```

Maybe try removing the #

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just set all values by hand in my theme, it seems like the "Theme Options" menu was not saving my values anymore, causing the synatx error,